# Chatterbot: Disabling learning feature doesn't work

Tags: python, chatterbot

According to the chatterbot doc, if I want to disable the learning feature after my bot has been trained, I can set `read_only=True` as a parameter when initializing the bot. So I do that but when I run the program, it keeps training. Below code I have

```
bot = ChatBot(
    "Terminal",
    read_only = "True",
    storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
    logic_adapters=[
        "chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
        "chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
        "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
    ],
    input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
    output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
    database="./databaseTrain.db"
)
```

What am I missing? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give Python `boolean values` to the `read_only` parameter.

```
bot = ChatBot(
    "Terminal",
    read_only=True,
)
```

Comment: I did that but still have the same issue